# Bootstrap Switch manual switch event

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-switch

I am using Bootstrap Switch, and needed to make an exclusive select: there are a bunch of switchers (unknown amount), and the user can turn one just one at a time.

I did something like this:

```
$('.switcher').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function() {
    $(".switcher[id!='"+selected_id+"']").each(function() {
        $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state', false);
    });
    $('#'+selected_id).bootstrapSwitch('state', current_state);
});
```

Unfortunately, this sends the script on an infinite loop (upon state change). I think this is because under the hood, Bootstrap Switch uses a trigger() function, so when the switch state is changed to false, it triggers the switchChange event again, and so on.

I made a workaround, by triggering:

```
$("#some-container .bootstrap-switch-container *").click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Instead. However, this seems like a really really bad solution.

Is there a better way?

Comment: The HTML is not really relevant to this question, Bootstrap Switch changes it completely anyway. You start with a checkbox, like <input type="checkbox">, then do $('input[type="checkbox"]').bootstrapSwitch(); and it adds some divs on top of the checkbox.

Comment: HTML is always relevant, it helps us to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run into same problem yesterday. Solution was found in [documentation](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/methods.html). In your case you must provide 3rd parameter set to false:

```
$('#'+selected_id).bootstrapSwitch('state', current_state, true);
```

This parameter (named `skip`) must be provided and set to true when you don't need to trigger switchChange event(-s).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function? You could remove the event handler (causing the infinite loop), changing the state of the switches and then attaches the handler back on.